How to use CUDA to decode video in FFmpeg.AutoGen?
FFmpeg.AutoGen version: 7.0
Following is similar with Program.cs in "FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example" directory.
var sourceSize = vsd.FrameSize;
var sourcePixelFormat = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_CUDA;
var destinationSize = sourceSize;
var destinationPixelFormat = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA;
VideoFrameConverter vfc = new VideoFrameConverter(sourceSize, sourcePixelFormat, destinationSize, destinationPixelFormat);

However, when 'ffmpeg.sws_getContext' is called, ffmpeg shows below error message.
ffmpeg error message: [swscaler @ 000001b7af30aa00] cuda is not supported as input pixel format
What did I do incorrectly?
If I don't use CUDA, I don't have any problem to decode video.
And "VideoStreamDecoder" initialization is okay.
